# open policy agent - OPA - How to use --config-file from kubernetes configmap object

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, open-policy-agent

I am trying to setup my OPA as below.

1. OPA installed as a sidecar in Kubernetes
2. Policy will be managed as bundle
3. OPA policy will be stored and served from a separate service [ Bundle ]
4. OPA need to be configured using config-file to get the policy from external service
5. config-file will be stored as a config map in kubernetes.
6. That config map need to be used in --config-file

My config map in kubernetes

```
kubectl create configmap policyconfig --from-file=./config/config.yaml
```

My Sidecar OPA

```
 - name: opa
          image: openpolicyagent/opa:latest
          args:
            - "run"
            - "--server"
            - "--addr=0.0.0.0:443"
            - "--addr=0.0.0.0:8181"
            - "--config-file=policyconfig"
      volumes:
        - name: policyconfig
          configMap:
            name: policyconfig
```

Let me know if it is possible to implement in this way

Comment: Getting an issue : error: config error: open policyconfig: no such file or directory

Comment: - name: opa
          image: openpolicyagent/opa:latest
          args:
            - "run"
            - "--server"
            - "--addr=0.0.0.0:443"
            - "--addr=0.0.0.0:8181"
            - "--config-file=/config/config.yaml"
          volumeMounts:
            - readOnly: true
              mountPath: /config
              name: policyconfig
      volumes:
        - name: policyconfig
          configMap:
            name: policyconfig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [kube-mgmt](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/kube-mgmt) as sidecar for managing OPA on top of Kubernetes.

kube-mgmt automatically discovers policies stored in ConfigMaps in Kubernetes and loads them into OPA. kube-mgmt assumes a ConfigMap contains policies if the ConfigMap is:

1. Created in a namespace listed in the --policies option. If you specify --policies=* then kube-mgmt will look for policies in ALL namespaces.
2. Labelled with openpolicyagent.org/policy=rego

[image: opa]

https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/policy-enabled-kubernetes-with-open-policy-agent-3b612b3f0203

Update:

With your current setup and requirement you need to add a `volumeMounts` to make it work

```
 - name: opa
          image: openpolicyagent/opa:latest
          args:
            - "run"
            - "--server"
            - "--addr=0.0.0.0:443"
            - "--addr=0.0.0.0:8181"
            - "--config-file=policyconfig"
          volumeMounts:
          - name: policyconfig
            mountPath: /config
      volumes:
        - name: policyconfig
          configMap:
            name: policyconfig
```

Comment: does it mean ,, i will have two sidecar for each primary microservice .. one is OPA and other is kube-mgmt ..

Comment: no this will be a sidecar within the OPA deployment https://github.com/open-policy-agent/kube-mgmt/blob/master/manifests/deployment.yml

Comment: ok .. mean it is a sidecar within OPA sidecar .. is my understanding correct .. in the example it is not installed OPA as sidecar .. but my requirement to install OPA as sidecar ..

Comment: Thanks Arghya, done ..and ans is                                                                                                   - name: opa
          image: openpolicyagent/opa:latest
          args:
            - "run"
            - "--server"
            - "--addr=0.0.0.0:443"
            - "--addr=0.0.0.0:8181"
            - "--config-file=/config/config.yaml"
          volumeMounts:
            - readOnly: true
              mountPath: /config
              name: policyconfig
      volumes:
        - name: policyconfig
          configMap:
            name: policyconfig

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use [Gatekeeper](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper). Which in addition to what [kube-mgmt](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/kube-mgmt) (Gatekeeper 1.0) has it also provides (per [this](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper#how-is-gatekeeper-different-from-opa)):

- An extensible, parameterized policy library
- Native Kubernetes CRDs for instantiating the policy library (aka "constraints")
- Native Kubernetes CRDs for extending the policy library (aka "constraint
  templates")
- Audit functionality

Another recent tool is [MagTape](https://github.com/tmobile/magtape).

Comment: Gatekeeper does seem to be the future of OPA in K8s

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Thanks!

Comment: oh I just meant that while you can run OPA in Kubernetes by itself, Gatekeeper is (going to be) the future of running OPA in K8s.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I am also trying to achieve the same goal - through Envoy to OPA using bundle API.

My bundle-API configuration –

```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    name: policyconfig
  data:
    config.yaml: |
      services:
        - name: controller
          url: https://opa-bundle-bucket1.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/bundles/authz.gz
      bundles:
        envoy/authz:
          service: controller
          resource: authz.gz
          polling:
            min_delay_seconds: 10
            max_delay_seconds: 20
      plugins:
        envoy_ext_authz_grpc:
          addr: :9191
          path: envoy/authz/allow
          dry-run: false
          enable-reflection: false
```

My config map in kubernetes -
kubectl create configmap policyconfig --from-file=./config/config.yaml

My Sidecar OPA -

```
  - name: opa
  # the latest released image of OPA-Envoy.
  image: openpolicyagent/opa:latest-envoy
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1111
  volumeMounts:
  - readOnly: true
    mountPath: /config
    name: policyconfig
  args:
  - "run"
  - "--server"
  - "--addr=localhost:8181"
  - "--diagnostic-addr=0.0.0.0:8282"
  - "--set=plugins.envoy_ext_authz_grpc.addr=:9191"
  - "--set=plugins.envoy_ext_authz_grpc.query=data.envoy.authz.allow"
  - "--set=decision_logs.console=true"
  - "--ignore=.*"
  - "--config-file=/config/config.yaml"
    volumes:
    - name: policyconfig
    configMap:
      name: policyconfig
```

Expected Behavior:-
Envoy will call OPA and OPA will send the request to the bundle-server to get the latest policy and data .

Actual Behavior :-
Envoy is calling OPA but OPA policies are not able to download.

```
Let me know what I am doing wrong here.
```